# TypeError: an integer is required(got type str) from a Request

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to download a list of URLs and download them. It doesn't work too well. It throws out an error like so:

"TypeError: an integer is required(got type str)"

```
import os
loc = requests.get("https://theipaarchive.tk/listofipa.txt")
listofipa = os.open(loc.content, "rt")
for line in listofipa:
  r = requests.get(line)
```

It occurs on line 4. hmm

Comment: Given the name `loc.content`, I suspect you want `io.StringIO`, not `os.open`.

Comment: What is io.StringIO from?

Comment: It's from the `io` module.

Comment: io.StringIO throws out an similar error. TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: if `bytes`: `for line in loc.content.encode('utf-8').split('\n'):`, if `str`: `for line in loc.content.split('\n'):`

Comment: What's the exact stack trace? Your original error complained that you *had* a `str`. (That said, you can use `io.BytesIO` instead.)

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper You *decode* a `bytes` value.

Comment: right, I mix those up a lot :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
import requests
loc = requests.get("https://theipaarchive.tk/listofipa.txt")
for line in loc.iter_lines():
    file = requests.get(line)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the way your file is written, you should just write :

```
import os
loc = requests.get("https://theipaarchive.tk/listofipa.txt")
listofipa = os.open(loc.text, "rt")
for line in listofipa:
  r = requests.get(line)
```